# downloading .tar.gz file from nodejs server using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to download a tar.gz file from server which gets created at run time. Here is the code at the server side

```
function downloadFile(req, res) {
  //some code to generate the tar file
  var file = ... code to compute the path ...
  res.download(file);
}
```

The method which calls this from the client side looks like this

```
  continueWithApplication(app) {
    this.$http.get('/api/applications/get-agent/' + app._id + '/' + this.nodeName).then(res => {
      var data = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/x-gzip' });
      this.FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'agent-1.0.tar.gz');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert('error downloading agent.');
    });
  }
```

I am using [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) to get the file downloaded.

I can see the file getting downloaded but when i try to untar the file it doesn't untar the content but creates a file with .cpgz extension. I have verified that the file that gets generated at server side is a valid .tar.gz file by unzipping it. Below screeen shot shows what happens when i try to untar the dowaloaded file (agent-1.0.tar.tar.gz -> agent-1.0.tar.gz.cpgz)

[image]

Any idea what am i doing wrong? Any pointer is deeply appreciated.

P.S. Please pardon my limited knowledge of angular and mean stack.

Comment: did you solved it?

Comment: No, i couldn't figure this out